# Slow performance of combined fast MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 queries that run very fast when ran separately, but when combined by using one of them as a subquery, the performance degrades drastically.

**FAST QUERY I:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_image, 
                p.products_subimage1, 
                pd.products_name, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_model, 
                p.products_ordered, 
                p.products_id, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_weight, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_tax_class_id, 
                p.products_status, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS 
                specials_new_products_price, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS 
                final_price 
FROM   products p 
       LEFT JOIN specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_to_categories p2c 
              ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_description pd 
              ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 

       LEFT JOIN products_attributes pa 
              ON p.products_id = pa.products_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `products_id`, 
               `products_stock_attributes`, 
               `products_stock_quantity` 
        FROM   products_stock 
        WHERE  `products_stock_quantity` > 0) t 
       ON t.products_id = p.products_id 
       WHERE t.products_stock_attributes IN ( '1-31', '1-25', '1-18', '1-7' ) 
       AND p.products_status = '1' 
       AND Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 30 day) >= p.products_date_added 
       AND pa.options_values_id IN ( 31, 25, 18, 7 ) 
GROUP  BY p.products_id 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT pa.options_values_id) = 4 
       AND Count(DISTINCT t.products_stock_attributes) = 4
```

**FAST QUERY II:**

```
SELECT sul2.* 
FROM   stock_update_log sul2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT products_id, 
     Max(date_time) AS maxDateTime 
FROM   stock_update_log 
WHERE  stock_qty_change > 1 
AND id > 154700 
   AND Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 360 day)<= From_unixtime(date_time) 
GROUP  BY products_id)gsul 
       ON sul2.products_id = gsul.products_id 
AND sul2.date_time = gsul.maxdatetime
```

**COMBINED QUERIES (VERY SLOW):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_image, 
                p.products_subimage1, 
                pd.products_name, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_model, 
                p.products_ordered, 
                p.products_id, 
                p.products_price, 
                sul.date_time, 
                p.products_weight, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_tax_class_id, 
                p.products_status, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS 
                specials_new_products_price, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS 
                final_price 
FROM   products p 
       LEFT JOIN specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_to_categories p2c 
              ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_description pd 
              ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT sul2.* 
                  FROM   stock_update_log sul2 
                         INNER JOIN (SELECT products_id, 
                                            Max(date_time) AS maxDateTime 
                                     FROM   stock_update_log 
                                     WHERE  stock_qty_change > 1 
                                            AND id > 154700 
                                            AND Date_sub(Curdate(), 
                                                INTERVAL 360 day) 
                                                <= 
                                                From_unixtime(date_time) 
                                     GROUP  BY products_id)gsul 
                                 ON sul2.products_id = gsul.products_id 
                                    AND sul2.date_time = gsul.maxdatetime) sul 
              ON p.products_id = sul.products_id 
       LEFT JOIN products_attributes pa 
              ON p.products_id = pa.products_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `products_id`, 
               `products_stock_attributes`, 
               `products_stock_quantity` 
        FROM   products_stock 
        WHERE  `products_stock_quantity` > 0) t 
       ON t.products_id = p.products_id 
       WHERE t.products_stock_attributes IN ( '1-31', '1-25', '1-18', '1-7' ) 
       AND p.products_status = '1' 
       AND Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 360 day) <= From_unixtime(sul.date_time) 
       AND Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 30 day) >= p.products_date_added 
       AND sul.id > 154700 
       AND sul.stock_qty_change > 1 
       AND pa.options_values_id IN ( 31, 25, 18, 7 ) 
GROUP  BY p.products_id 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT pa.options_values_id) = 4 
       AND Count(DISTINCT t.products_stock_attributes) = 4 
ORDER  BY sul.date_time DESC
```

EXPLAIN of combined queries result:
[image: EXPLAIN of combined quries result]

I have been trying for hours to figure out why it get so slow when combining them this way and tried to rewrite the combined query to no avail, so I am reaching out for help from the experts here.

What can be the cause of it becoming so slow and what should I do to make it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query II feels like it has a million rows; the resulting tmp table has no index; and it is hidden behind a `LEFT JOIN`.  Still the optimizer seems to be smart enough to start with that mess and provide 7904 rows to the joint query.

Can you avoid `LEFT`?

Then the code progresses, but eventually has to check all those rows against 18057 rows from a table scan.  Again the Optimizer does a smart thing by using the "join buffer".  Still, 7904*923*18057 is a lot of rows to look at.

This seems to be the evil part:

```
   LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT `products_id`, 
              `products_stock_attributes`, 
              `products_stock_quantity` 
        FROM    products_stock 
        WHERE  `products_stock_quantity` > 0
    ) t 
   ON t.products_id = p.products_id 

   WHERE t.products_stock_attributes IN ( '1-31', '1-25', '1-18', '1-7' )
```

All of these seem to be red flags:

- Unnecessary(?) `LEFT`;
- "where attributes in..." outside the subquery when they could be inside;
- You could probably fold the `HAVING Count(DISTINCT t.products_stock_attributes) = 4` into the subquery.

Comment: Yes, moving the `WHERE t.products_stock_attributes IN` and `HAVING Count(DISTINCT t.products_stock_attributes) = 4` into this subquery solved the problem. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a join over 7 tables, which is sure to be very slow. I'd recommend avoiding joining more than about 3 tables.

Have you tried doing the two queries by themselves, and then combine their results?

Comment: Upvoting for trying to help me. Thank you. :)